# iOS UIKeyboardWillShow fires unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a `UITextView` and a `UITableView`, and I need to adjust the bottom position and scrolling of the `TableView` as the keyboard opens and closes, and so I setup notifications for the keyboard.  Not only do `KeyboardWillShow` and `KeyboardDidShow` fire when the keyboard opens (expected), they also fire when the view is loaded and also when the keyboard closes (NOT expected).  These are the only notifications set up in the app.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:  #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:  #selector(keyboardDidHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)


@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    print ("KEYBOARD WILL SHOW")
}
@objc func keyboardDidShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    print ("KEYBOARD DID SHOW")
}
@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    print ("KEYBOARD WILL HIDE")
}
@objc func keyboardDidHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    print ("KEYBOARD DID HIDE")
}
```

Clicking in  the `TextView` opens the keyboard, and dragging the `TableView` closes it. (`TableView` has been tested with "Dismiss interactively", and also "Dismiss on drag").

Here's the console output after loading the view, opening the keyboard, and closing of the keyboard:

View first loads (the keyboard is NOT open)....

`KEYBOARD WILL SHOW`   (NOT expected)

`KEYBOARD DID SHOW`    (NOT expected)

Keyboard opens...

`KEYBOARD WILL SHOW`   (expected)

`KEYBOARD DID SHOW`    (expected)

Keyboard closes...

`KEYBOARD WILL HIDE`   (expected)

`KEYBOARD WILL SHOW`   (NOT expected)

`KEYBOARD DID HIDE`    (expected)

`KEYBOARD DID SHOW`    (NOT expected)

Further, when the `TableView` is set to "Dismiss interactively" and I drag the `TableView` slowly downward, the "WillShow/DidShow" events fire like crazy starting when the keyboard is about 2/3 of the way closed.

What could possibly be causing these keyboard open events to fire?

Xcode 11.3/iOS 9.0

Answer (score 0):

It may be another, invisible view causing the keyboard to be shown or hidden. *Everyone* observing these events will get the notifications, including other views not currently active.

Comment: perhaps the inputAccessoryView that I have permanently anchored to the bottom ?